# How does one check for form completion using C# in Blazor?

Tags: c#, events, blazor

I am currently working a asp.net blazor project. In my displayed page, I have a set of form inputs under a collapsible. What I would like to do is set up some C# code to check when a user has completed all of the inputs, and take that information to make something happen in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnValidSubmit` and `OnInvalidSubmit` events on `EditForm` are what you need.

```
    @if (LastSubmitResult != null)
    {
      <h2>
        Last submit status: @LastSubmitResult
      </h2>
    }
    <EditForm Model=@Person OnValidSubmit=@ValidFormSubmitted OnInvalidSubmit=@InvalidFormSubmitted>
      <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
      <InputText For=Person.FirstName/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
    </EditForm>

    @code {
      Person Person = new Person();
      string LastSubmitResult;
      void ValidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
      {
        LastSubmitResult = "OnValidSubmit was executed";
      }
      void InvalidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
      {
        LastSubmitResult = "OnInvalidSubmit was executed";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was quite useful. God bless you and have a great week!

Comment: I have another issue related to your answer. OnValidSubmit only fires when the form data is submitted. However, I want the event to fire _as_ the user completes the form. This is because it is a long form with multiple sections. I need to give users a visual sign that they have filled in all of the inputs of a specific section _before_ submission. Help, please

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-form-validation/amp/